# When copy constructor is called from a temporary value in function argument

Tags: c++

I have a question on why the following snippet codes caused a stack overflow.

```
class vector {
private:

public:

    vector (const vector& rhs) {
         /*
        _b = (rhs.size() == 0) ? nullptr : new value_type[rhs.size()];
        _e = _b + rhs.size());
        copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), _b);
        } */
   }
```

So why does the code removed "&" from the argument like vector(const vector RHS) causing the stack overflow?

Comment: We need more code to diagnose that.

Comment: Looks like someone answered this on Quora of all places https://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-I-create-a-copy-constructor-in-C-that-takes-a-parameter-by-value-instead-of-by-reference

Comment: By the way, can you let us know how you called this? Writing such a "constructor" is illegal, producing `error: invalid constructor; you probably meant 'A (const A&)'
     A(const A x) {}`. Or are you using an old version of C++?

Comment: Oh never mind the last comment....it was targeted to an earlier version of the question. Now we can answer it, thanks!

Comment: Actually wait.... there's still not enough information....

Comment: You keep changing your question

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> A(const A RHS) { ...}
> ```

Isn't a copy constructor. A copy constructor would take a (`const`) reference to the type being copied. In your example however the parameter `RHS` itself needs to be copied.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my snippet according to your comments

Comment: A "constructor" like this, without the reference parameter, does not compile for me. So while it's true it's not a copy constructor, I think the bigger problem is that the code doesn't compile. Not sure how the OP got an infinite loop. Something is a little odd here. Does it compile for you?

Comment: @changnj This wasn't a comment but an answer to your original question. You claimed that using "`A(const A RHS) { ...}`" as a copy constructor caused a stack overflow. You can't simply alter your question and still claim to get the same result. I'm voting to close because it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here. I figured it out that I pass an argument by value in a copy constructor, a call to copy constructor would be made to call copy constructor which becomes a non-terminating chain of calls.